# How can I express Closing Price above or below SMA in R?

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

Glad to have found this community!

As a beginning project, I wish to examine what happens when you open a position when the price is above an SMA and close it once the price is below.

I am currently working on a script in R as follows:

```
`##############################
# 0 - Load libraries
##############################
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(TTR)

# Step 1: Get the data
loadSymbols("^GSPC")

# Step 2: Create your indicator
SMA <- SMA(x = (GSPC), n = 200)

# Step 3: Construct your trading rule
signal <- Lag(ifelse(SMA$SMA > CLV(GSPC), 1, -1))

# Step 4: The trading rules/equity curve
ret <- ROC(Cl(GSPC))*signal
ret <- ret[2009-06-02/2020-09-07]
eq <- exp(cumsum(ret))
plot(eq)

# Step 5: Evaluate strategy performance
table.Drawdowns(ret, top=10)
table.DownsideRisk(ret)
charts.PerformanceSummary(ret)
plot(cl(GSPC))
lines(sma, col = "Blue")`
```

The script does not produce any output when I run it. I have re-installed all packages and I am running R version 3.6.

Please can somebody tell me why?

Comment: First thing to do it to run the script line by line and see where the error is occuring. If you can't work out how to solve it yourself then edit the question to ask how giving more details (or ask a new more specific question).

Comment: Thanks @pseudospin I will do that.